# Launch a program in a just downloaded kernel 3.14

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I'm trying to understand linux kernel (well.. I just started).
I have downloaded the sources and I have compiled it (3.14).
I use Qemu to start the kernel and it works.
(and I build a rootfs)
here's my command:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel linux/arch/x86_64/boot/bzImage -hda rootfs/disk.img -append "root=/dev/sda console=ttyS0" -nographic ;
```

Before compiling, I have added some printk in the start_kernel function and I can see it.

Now I'm trying to launch a little C program. It's just a main which prints a "hello world" using **write** and returns 0;

I have compiled my program on my debian (3.14 kernel too), I copied it in the file where I have mounted the disk.img for the kernel.
When I start the kernel with Qemu, I make

```
/ # ./HelloWorld <br>
```

but nothing happens.

After, I put exit(EXIT_FAILURE) on the HelloWorld.
so I have :

```
/ # ./HelloWorld <br>
/ # echo $? <br>
0
```

instead of 1.

And sometimes I have :

```
/ # ./HelloWorld <br>
-/bin/sh: ./HelloWorld: not found
```

I put all the permissions for everybody on that program.

I'don't understand why it doesn't work? Is this because I copied the program? Must I have to install gcc and others things to compile directly in Qemu?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to use `strace` ; perhaps link statically your program.

Comment: omg... I just tried to link statically it works... I though it was somethings so complicated I didn't think about that.
Thanks!